# Rays within a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create the same figure as the one posted in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337297/tikz-pic-angle-around-circle) (see reply) but centered around a different point than (0,0). Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried something? I guess if you change `(0,0)` to something else it'll do what you want.

Comment: That does not work as it would draw lines from (x,y) to points along a circle of radius `\Radius` centered at(0,0). The reply below, with the `+`, works exactly as I needed. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a `do-it-for-me` question. Hence a -1.

Comment: @Raaja The OP is a new contributor, wait a bit before closing, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Define a coordinate which should be the center point, state this first to all commands and then add a `+` before each coordinate. The plus sign makes the following coordinate relative to the one without a plus sign which then is exactly what you want. See Heiko's modified code to which I also added a red circle at (0,0) to prove that the center really is not there any more, but at the defined coordinate (A).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
  \def\Radius{2.5cm}
  \draw
    \foreach \a in {10, 20, ..., 350} {
      (A) -- +(\a:\Radius)
    }
    +(0, 0) circle[radius=\Radius]
    %
    +(0, 0) -- +(0:3.75cm)
    +(0, 0) -- +(10:3.75cm)
    %
    +(5:4cm) node {\SI{10}{\degree}}
    +(-30:3.7cm) node {\SI{360}{\degree}}
  ;

  \def\Radius{3.5cm}
  \draw[->]
    (A)
    +(0:\Radius) arc[start angle=0, end angle=10, radius=\Radius]
  ;

  \def\Radius{3cm}
  \draw[->]
    (A)
    +(0:\Radius)
    arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=\Radius]
    arc[start angle=180, end angle=360, radius=\Radius]
  ;
    \fill [red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: It is probably simpler to use shifted scope, no ?

Comment: @Kpym, this would be another possibility. And I am pretty sure there are even more. Feel free to write an answer, too. This is what this site is all about, as you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility : define a `pic` that you can place where you want after that.
This is interesting only if you need to place the wheel multiple times.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\tikzset{
  wheel/.pic={
    \def\Radius{2.5cm}
    \draw
      \foreach \a in {10, 20, ..., 350}{
        (0,0) -- +(\a:\Radius)
      }
      (0, 0) circle[radius=\Radius]
      (0, 0) -- +(0:3.75cm)
      (0, 0) -- +(10:3.75cm)
      (5:4cm) node {\SI{10}{\degree}}
      (-30:3.7cm) node {\SI{360}{\degree}}
    ;

    \def\Radius{3.5cm}
    \draw[->]
      (0:\Radius) arc[start angle=0, end angle=10, radius=\Radius]
    ;

    \def\Radius{3cm}
    \draw[->]
      (0:\Radius)
      arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=\Radius]
      arc[start angle=180, end angle=360, radius=\Radius]
    ;
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[orange] (-1,-1) rectangle (11,3);
  \path  (0,0) pic{wheel} (10,0) pic{wheel};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]